# Best way to find overlapped date range in case of multi million data?

Tags: mysql, date, overlap, date-range

I'm working on a reservation system which is working fine, and I have done the below to find available cars in a date range.

```
Table1 -> cars

| id | registration |
| 1  | 1111111      |
| 2  | 222222       |
| 3  | 3333         |
| 4  | 44444        |


Table2 -> reservation

| id |  dateFrom  |   dateTo   |
| 1  | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-04 |
| 2  | 2017-12-04 | 2017-12-07 |
| 3  | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-02 |
| 3  | 2017-12-03 | 2017-12-05 |
| 3  | 2017-12-06 | 2017-12-07 |
| 4  | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-03 |

Now I need to get cars which don't have reservations from 2017-12-05 to 2017-12-06

SELECT * FROM cars  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM reservation 
WHERE cars.id = reservation.carId AND
dateFrom <= '2017-12-06' AND
dateTo >= '2017-12-05' )
```

Its working smoothly cause it follows very simple logic. But I'm worry about its performance. If I have multi millions of data in reservation table, in that case should I run this query to find available cars in a date range??

If not what will be the solutions??

Comment: Appropriately indexed, this query should be just fine (except you should never use SELECT *). Note also that  you wouldn't normally want '=' on both ends of the overlap

Comment: @Strawberry Do you suggest to remove '=' by decreasing dateFrom & increasing dateTo by one day each? Will it affect performance? And yes index are done properly.

Comment: The comparison is usually `[>=,<]` or `[>,<=]`

Comment: @Strawberry but both the days are inclusive here. So either I have to decrese fromDate or increase toDate and then check.

Comment: I think most bookings operate on a 'closed-open system'. If I book a car from 22 May through 24 May, most operators would (I think) expect the vehice to be available for hire on the 24th. if that's not how your system works then you can ignore that part of my comment; it's not a performance issue.